# Replicate `layout` in `grid`/`ggplot`

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to replicate the following code, except with histograms being replaced with `ggplot` calls. So, this works:

```
layout(matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5), ncol=3))
hist(1:20)
hist(1:40)
hist(1:60)
hist(1:80)
hist(1:90)
```

And this doesn't (each ggplot creates a new full-scale image instead of being part of the layout):

```
layout(matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5), ncol=3))
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:20)) + stat_bin(aes(x=x))
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:40)) + stat_bin(aes(x=x))
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:60)) + stat_bin(aes(x=x))
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:80)) + stat_bin(aes(x=x))
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:90)) + stat_bin(aes(x=x))
```

The first piece of code produces the following layout:

[image]

How do I use `ggplot` to arrange plots the same way the first `layout` call does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`layout()` only works with base graphics. ggplot uses grid graphics which has a different way or arranging plots. Try checking out the [multiplot helper function](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/). It has a `layout=` parameter very similar to the `layout` function. For example

```
multiplot(layout=matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5), ncol=3),
    ggplot(data.frame(x=1:20)) + stat_bin(aes(x=x)),
    ggplot(data.frame(x=1:40)) + stat_bin(aes(x=x)),
    ggplot(data.frame(x=1:60)) + stat_bin(aes(x=x)),
    ggplot(data.frame(x=1:80)) + stat_bin(aes(x=x)),
    ggplot(data.frame(x=1:90)) + stat_bin(aes(x=x))
)
```

[image]